# Issue Generating Code - Grabbing values from the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

In relation to the following, I want the code to generate when form is submitted. I have added a button to clone a block within the form (giving the option of adding another batch of skus) and have a remove option button aswell if required to remove this before submission.

The issue I'm having is that I am adding the cloned element manually when getting the content from the DOM(document.getElementbyId). The form, at present, only seems to allow me to add when the second list of skus are added.

I just want to know if there is a was to retrieve the values depending on whether there is 1 or 2 list of skus. I'm sure there's a better/more dynamic way of outputting the content rather that this which doesn't seem to work:

```
product_widget_start + "<br />" + product_title + "<br />" + product_skus + 
 "<br />" + product_widget_end + "<br /><br />" + product_widget_start + " 
<br />" + product_title_2 + "<br />" + product_skus_2 + "<br />" + 
 product_widget_end
```

Full Example

```js
/*trial for clone and swap ids*/
$(document).ready(function() {

    var currentID = 1;

    $(':button#adder').on('click', function() {
        currentID++;

        var clone = $('#product_skus').clone();
        clone.attr('id', 'product_skus-1');

        clone.children('.carous_title').attr('id', 'title_carousel-' + currentID);
        clone.children('.carous_skus').attr('id', 'skus-' + currentID);

        clone.appendTo('#product_skus');

    });

    $(':button#adder1').on('click', function() {
        $(".sku_names").last().remove();
    });


});


function myFunction() {

    /*CREATION OF MAIN BANNER/HEADER WIDGET*/

    /*widget start*/

    var quote = '"';

    var header_widget_start = "{{widget type=" + quote + "banner" + quote;
    var header_title = "title=" + quote + document.getElementById("title").value + quote;
    var header_desc = "description=" + quote + document.getElementById("desc").value + quote;
    var header_alt = "alt=" + quote + document.getElementById("alt").value + quote;
    var header_img_url = "image_large=" + quote + document.getElementById("img_url").value + quote;
    var header_widget_end = "template=" + quote + "banner" + quote + "}}";

    /*widget end*/

    /*END OF CREATION OF MAIN BANNER/HEADER WIDGET*/


    /*CREATION OF PRODUCT SKUS WIDGET*/

    /*widget start*/

    var product_widget_start = "{{widget=" + quote + "cat" + quote + "<br />" + "limit=" + quote + "4" + quote;
    var product_title = "title=" + quote + document.getElementById("title_carousel").value + quote;
    var product_skus = "product_skus=" + quote + document.getElementById("skus").value + quote;
    var product_widget_end = "template=" + quote + "skus" + quote + "}}";

    /*widget end*/

    /*optional second widget*/

    var product_title_2 = "title=" + quote + document.getElementById("title_carousel-2").value + quote;
    var product_skus_2 = "product_skus=" + quote + document.getElementById("skus-2").value + quote;

    /*optional second widget end*/

    /*END OF CREATION OF PRODUCT SKUS WIDGET*/

    document.getElementById("top").innerHTML = header_widget_start + "<br />" + header_title + "<br />" + header_desc + "<br />" + header_alt + "<br />" + header_img_url + "<br />" + header_widget_end + "<br /><br />" + product_widget_start + "<br />" + product_title + "<br />" + product_skus + "<br />" + product_widget_end + "<br /><br />" + product_widget_start + "<br />" + product_title_2 + "<br />" + product_skus_2 + "<br />" + product_widget_end;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

<div id = "content_left" style = "float:left; width:48%;">

          <form action="" method="post">

                  <h1>Generate</h1>

                  <fieldset>

                    <legend><span class="number">1</span>Header</legend>

                    <label for="name">Title:</label>

                    <input type = "text" id = "title" />

                    <label for="mail">Description:</label>

                    <textarea id = "desc" rows="5" cols="20" /></textarea>

                    <label for="password">Alt:</label>

                    <input type = "text" id = "alt" />

                    <label for="password">Image URL:</label>

                    <input type = "text" id = "img_url" />

                  </fieldset>

                  <fieldset>

                    <legend><span class="number">2</span>Mobile</legend>

                    <label for="name">Title:</label>

                    <input type = "text" id = "" />

                    <label for="mail">Text Colour:</label>

                    <input type = "text" id = "" />

                  </fieldset>

                                          <fieldset class = "sku_names" id = "product_skus">

                    <legend><span class="number">3</span>Product</legend>

                    <label for="name">Title :</label>

                    <input class = "carous_title" type = "text" id = "title_carousel" />

                    <label for="mail">Skus:</label>

                    <input class = "carous_skus" type = "text" id = "skus" />

                  </fieldset>

                  <input id = "adder" type = "button" value = "Add" />
                  <input id = "adder1" type = "button" value = "Remove" />

                </form>

                <button onClick="myFunction()">Generate Code</button>

</div>

<div id = "content_right" style = "float:left; width:48%; padding-left:10px;">

<pre><div></pre>
    <p id="top">

    </p>

    <p id="test1"></p>

</div>

</div>


<script>


  </script>
```

Comment: What does `The form, at present, only seems to allow me to add when the second list of skus are added.` mean?

Comment: It means the when the submit button is clicked first, no code is generated. However, if the add button is clicked (adding additional skus), then the generation of code works when the submit button is clicked